# click event to fire just once

Tags: jquery

i want the click() event to fire just once. 
I can use the removeClass() but doesnt sounds good if i need it again for smthing else.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to have an event fire just once:

```
$('#item').one('click', function() {
    alert("You'll never see me again!");
});
```

Comment: I didn't even know .one() existed. nice one!